# Laravel 8.x Is there any way to bind CustomLogger using monolog with DateTimeZone set via Service Providers

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I'd like to override all of Laravel logger's dateTimeZone to 'Asia/Tokyo', but not changing `config/app.php => timezone`.

Laravel comes with `monolog` library by default, and basically `Illuminate\Log\LogManager` is doing all the work to instantiate `Monolog\Logger` objects.

We can pass `DateTimeZone` object to `Monolog\Logger` constructor's 4th argument, but there is no way we can pass that to `LogManager` via `config/logging.php` or anything.

I know that there's a way to create custom logger object with full control and register to custom channel.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#creating-custom-channels-via-factories

One way is that I'll create & use `App\Logging\CreateCustomLoggerWithTokyoTimeZone::class` and modify all of the default existing channels.

The other way is that I'll somehow override `LogManager` and bind it to service container 's `log` service. (override `log` service, but it's a singleton)

Any good ideas? Anything is appreciated.